# Stylesheet Error

Tags: css, html

When I validate the code on "http://validator.w3.org/check,"

I get 3 errors, I can't figure out why? This is a style sheet(css). Below is the code:

```
body { background-color: #ffffcc;
     color: #330000;
     font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; }

h1 { background-color: ccaa66;   
     color: #000000;text-align: center;
     line-height: 200%;}

#Nav {text-align: center:}
#footer {background-color: #ccaa66;
        color: #000000;
                font-size: .60em;
        text-align: center;
        font-style: italic;}
#wrapper {margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 80%;}
```

The three errors are:

Line 1, Column 1: character "b" not allowed in prolog

Line 11, Column 3: character "c" not allowed in prolog

Line 17, Column 15: end of document in prolog

Comment: That's a HTML validator.... you want the [CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input)

Comment: rookie mistake! Code is perfect thank you

Comment: +1 @sachleen, also the #Nav tag has a Colon instead of a semi-colon after the word center.

Answer (score 3):

You linked to an HTML validator. Did you mean to link to the [CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)?